# IWbemServices ExecMethod fails with 0x80070005 (Access Denied) in C++

Tags: c++, wmi

I am having a C++ Application to access WMI namespace the source code looks below,

```
    // Create instance of IWbemLocator 
    IWbemLocator *pLocator = nullptr;
    HRESULT hResult = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&pLocator);
  
    if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && pLocator != nullptr)
    {
     
        hResult = pLocator->ConnectServer(
            _T("\\SERVERNAME\\root\\NAMESPACE")
            nullptr,        // User name
            nullptr,        // User password
            nullptr,        // Locale             
            0,      // Security flags
            nullptr,        // Authority        
            nullptr,        // Context object 
            &pNamespace // IWbemServices proxy
        );

        if (SUCCEEDED(hResult) && pNamespace != nullptr)
        {
              hResult = pNamespace->ExecMethod(_T("ClassPath"), _T("MethodName"), 0, NULL, NULL, &pOutInst, NULL);
        }
    }
```

This code works fine in one of my machine. In another machine It fails in pNamespace->ExecMethod(....) call with 0x80070005 (Access Denied) error.

I checked permissions on wmimgmt.msc.

If I use wbemtest tool, I am able to execute the same method.

Any suggestions to trouble shoot. Thanks.

Comment: After I make call to CoSetProxyBlanket as specified in this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/setting-authentication-using-c- , the issue is resolved. But in some machines, this works without CoSetProxyBlanket call. Some machines only access denied error occurs without CoSetProxyBlanket call. Anyone has any idea?